# Django template variables are lost when displaying form errors

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

Problem description (Django 1.7):-

1. Simple form is rendered containing input fields and some template variables. The template variables are set in the supporting view and show some boilerplate legal text.
2. I have a custom "clean" method that checks the input field values and sets validation errors as needed.
3. If errors have occurred, the form is re-displayed with the correct error messages by the fields that are in error.

However, the template variables are lost, i.e.

{{ my-template-variable }} that when the form is initially rendered is OK is then not set when the form is re-rendered to show the errors.

I understand why this is happening, but can anyone advise how I can reset the template variable in the clean method so this works as expected?

Here's the code:-

views.py

```
def form1(request):

    legal_text = "Some long legal paragraph ...."

    if request.method == 'POST':
            form = form1(request.POST)
            # do stuff with the posted values ...

    else:
            form = form1()

    return render(request,'form11.html', {'form': form, 'legal_text': legal_text})
```

forms.py

```
class form1(forms.Form):

    # form contains lots of input questions 'q1', 'q2' etc that are cross-validated

    def clean(self):
            cleaned_data = super(form1,self).clean()
            if not cleaned_data.get('q1'):
                    self._errors['q1'] = 'Please provide a selection'

            if not cleaned_data.get('q2'):
                    self._errors['q2'] = 'Please provide a selection'

     Q1_CHOICES = (('10', 'Yes',), ('01', 'No',),)
     q1 = forms.ChoiceField(required=False,label="This is question 1",help_text="Some arbitrary help text",widget=forms.RadioSelect,choices=Q1_CHOICES)

     Q2_CHOICES = (('10', 'Yes',), ('01', 'No',),)
     q2 = forms.ChoiceField(required=False,label="This is question 1",help_text="Some arbitrary help text",widget=forms.RadioSelect,choices=Q2_CHOICES)

     # more questions omitted ...
```

form1.html (snippet)

```
<html>
  <body>
    {{ legal_text }} <!-- this is NOT displayed properly when errors occur -->

     <h4><strong>{{ form.q1.label }}</strong></h4>
     {% if form.q1.errors %}
           <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">{{form.q1.errors }}</div>
     {% endif %}
     <br/>
     {{ form.q1.help_text }}
     <br/><br/>
     {{ form.q1 }}
     <br/>
     <h4><strong>{{ form.q2.label }}</strong></h4>
     {% if form.q2.errors %}
           <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">{{form.q2.errors }}</div>
     {% endif %}
     <br/>
     {{ form.q2.help_text }}
     <br/><br/>
     {{ form.q2 }}

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Show us the code! Also, if custom validation is the issue, why not use custom validators instead of overriding `clean`?

Comment: You don't do anything with template variables in the clean method, you do it in the view. Which you should show.

Comment: Thanks - code added - hope this is useful

Comment: In the code you've posted, legal_text should definitely show when the form is not valid.

Comment: Thanks - I had mis-configured the form postback. All OK now

Answer (score 0):

Here you are overriding the form clean method and not returning clean_data. Replace your code like

```
def clean(self):
   cleaned_data = super(form1,self).clean()
   if not cleaned_data.get('q1'):
      self._errors['q1'] = 'Please provide a selection'

   if not cleaned_data.get('q2'):
      self._errors['q2'] = 'Please provide a selection'

   return self.cleaned_data
```

Comment: While this is true, it has nothing to do with the OP's problem.